# Lyrics of Wilf Carter's Why should I feel sorry for you now

Tags: lyrics

I really do like this old song:
Wilf Carter's *Why should I feel sorry for you now*

I'd like to have the lyrics. I have searched the lyrics on the internet, but there is nothing. So I typed the lyrics by myself. **Could anyone help me check it?** Some lyrics I don't know what he was singing were marked as a question mark.

(*) Why should I feel sorry for you now
You are the one who shattered every bound
I believed in you
But you proved untrue
Why should I feel sorry for you now

I remember on that very day
When I beg you not to go away
But you didn't care
You left me in despair
Why should I feel sorry for you now

(*)

Why should I forgive you and forget
Scars upon my heart ??? a million
Now my eyes are dry
It's your turn to cry
Why should I feel sorry for you now

(*)

Why should I feel sorry over you
You just laughed ???
Though your eyes are wet
I'm learning to forgive
Why should I feel sorry for you now

(*)

Comment: I've been reminded that posting the full lyrics to a song is likely to violate copyright law, so I've rewritten my answer to address only the corrections. I suggest you rewrite your question to include only the lines for which I've given corrections. Otherwise, there is the possibility of the question being deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrections and additions in bold.

---

- **You're** the one who shattered every **vow**
- I remember on that **dreary** day
- When I **begged** you not to go away
- Scars upon my heart **are not healed yet**
- You just laughed **at me when I fell blue**
- I'm learning to **forget**